# Change Keys in Mysql Associative array to Human Readable Keys using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql tables one stores data about the users such as

```
  user_id | user_name |  user_email_address
     1    |  john232  |  john232@someemail.com
     2    |  Lisa122  |  Lisa1232@someemail.com
```

The second table is a definition table stores data like this:

```
  table_id | table_name | table_column       | column_label
      1    | user       | user_name          | User Name 
      2    | user       | user_email_address | Email Address
```

In the end what I am trying to accomplish is when data is retrieved the data from users table it looks like this.

```
   Array
  (
  [0] => Array
     (
        [user_id] => 1
        [user_name] => john232
        [user_email_address] => john232@someemail.com
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 2
        [user_name] => Lisa122 
        [user_email_address] => Lisa1232@someemail.com
    )
  )
```

The data needs to be transformed like this:

```
   Array
  (
  [0] => Array
     (
        [User ID] => 1
        [User Name] => john232
        [Email Address] => john232@someemail.com
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [User ID] => 2
        [User Name] => Lisa122 
        [Email Address] => Lisa1232@someemail.com
    )
  )
```

Any help in the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example, you should replace `$data` for your own data.

```
<?
$data = array(
    array('user_id' => 1, 'user_name' => 'john232', 'user_email_address' => 'john232@someemail.com'),
    array('user_id' => 1, 'user_name' => 'john232', 'user_email_address' => 'john232@someemail.com'),
);
$humanReadable = array('user_id' => 'User ID', 'user_name' => 'User Name', 'user_email_address' => 'Email');
$restul = array();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $newRow = array();
    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $humanReadable)) {
            $newRow[$humanReadable[$key]] = $value;
        } else {
            $newRow[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    $result[] = $newRow;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

This produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User ID] => 1
            [User Name] => john232
            [Email] => john232@someemail.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [User ID] => 1
            [User Name] => john232
            [Email] => john232@someemail.com
        )

)
```

Comment: I like your solution, i do have a question for the second array called $humanReadable you have association like this 'user_id' => 'User ID', but when i output the associative array from the second table, my information looks like [table_column] => user_name [column_label] => User Name, which if am reading you right you don't use the second table at all..which is a requirement, because it already exists (I am building off my co-workers already designed database).

Comment: You should populate the **$humanReadable** array with your other table data.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need PHP to do this - save yourself from a ton of unnecessary work; you can change your SQL to use the AS keyword to alias column names. For example

```
SELECT user_id AS "User ID", user_name AS "User Name", user_email_address AS "Email Address" FROM user_table;
```

This is also helpful if you wanna alias your counts or the like, example:

```
SELECT count(*) AS "Total Users" FROM user_table;

Total Users
-----------
500
```

On another note, you may want to give some greater consideration to your choice to have associative keys with spaces in the naming, just out of convention, it is probably not the best practice.

Comment: I thought about this ideal as well as a possible solution, but my co-worker already created a second table with those type of definitions, he wants me to use that to create the array for processing by a front end application. When you have a say a registration form that users fill out.  What he wants the column names to show as labels and having items show up like street_address isn't good practice.

Comment: This wont change the database at all, this is the query that is taking the data out of the database, it is your select statement, which would be executed in the PHP app.

Comment: Also, having a table to label the columns serves no purpose, since aliasing exists.

Comment: this is only for my education what if you have like 50 columns do you need to go in and use AS for all 50 columns?

Comment: I totally agree with you on the second table wasn't mine design, if i could change it i would. I proposed Alias got told to try it this way first.

Comment: Ideally, if you have 50 columns that needed to be aliased, yes, you'd do it this way as well, you have the query in front of you anyway - you shouldn't be using Select * because it doesn't indicate to other programmers what they should expect to be coming back for columns and just makes things difficult to maintain in general. Plus at any time with a Select * a DBA may drop sensitive info in that table that u dont want to expose. Plus, the performance hit you're going to take doing this in PHP over a column alias in SQL is MASSIVE look at the code below, the asymptotic runtime of that is On^2